# A few Aliases to map to the same MVC Controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

i have a ASP.NET MVC5 website and i would like to have it load the same page from a few Urls

i should be able to get the the `mapsController` by all this URLs

```
/Maps
/Map
/Location
/Locations
```

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: If its a publicly available site, google will not like this unless you implement it as redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want Attribute Routing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

e.g.

```
[Route("/Maps")]
[Route("/Map")]
[Route("/Locations")]
[Route("/Location")]
public ActionResult Action () { ... }
```